# How does one toggle the selected row in a UITableViewContoller / UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

A LOT has changed with respect to the code as I've been trying to debug this over the last week or so - as such, I've moved the original posting to a [PDF](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21776252/ORIGINAL_ios%20-%20How%20does%20one%20toggle%20the%20selected%20row%20in%20a%20UITableViewContoller%20-%20UITableViewCell%20-%20Stack%20Overflow%20copy.pdf) and am starting *mostly* fresh here:

**Short-ish synopsis:** (*largely unchanged*)

- A `UITableViewController` (with a custom class) that contains
  `UITableViewCell`'s (also custom class)
- Table defined to only allow for single selections
- Initial "empty" cell (row = 0) setup to provide some padding at top
  of view
- Want to be able to toggle selection of cells (click it once,
  selected; click it again, un-selected)
- Code I have looks (to me) like it should work, but doesn't
- So, looking for some guidance / assistance / etc.

**Code**

Below is the [relevant portions of the] custom `UITableViewController` code (slightly re-formatted)

```
import UIKit

class ExistingLocationsViewController: UITableViewController {
    var oldRow = -9999
    var newRow = -1
    var locationList: [LocationObject] = [
        LocationObject(name: "name-1", address: "addr-1", phone: "phone-1", latitude: 40.0, longitude: -80.1),
        LocationObject(name: "name-2", address: "addr=2", phone: "phone-2", latitude: 40.0, longitude: -80.1)
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // provides buffer space at the top so that the contents do not run into the top-margin (not needed if first cell is [intnetionally] blank)
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    //... didReceiveMemoryWarning, numberOfSectionsInTableView, tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
    // Did an override of willDisplayCell, but it seemed to neither hurt nor help my issue, so I removed it

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("resultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExistingLocationTableViewCell
        let row  = indexPath.row
        let item = locationList[row]

        cell.nameLabel.text     = item.name
        cell.locationLabel.text = item.address

        print("cellForRowAtIndexPath: (row = \(row))(oldRow = \(oldRow))(newRow = \(newRow))[cell.selected = \(cell.selected)]")
        //...attempt to set cell.accessoryType here neither hurt nor helped my issue, so I removed them

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("resultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExistingLocationTableViewCell
        print("didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: (row = \(indexPath.row))(oldRow = \(oldRow))(newRow = \(newRow))[cell.selected = \(cell.selected)]")
        print("didDeselectRowAtIndexPath => reloadRowsAtIndexPaths")
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("resultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExistingLocationTableViewCell
        newRow = indexPath.row
        print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (row = \(indexPath.row))(oldRow = \(oldRow))(newRow = \(newRow))[cell.selected = \(cell.selected)]")
        if newRow == oldRow  {
            print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath => didDeselectRowAtIndexPath")
            self.tableView(tableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell.setSelected(false, animated: false) // before or after call to didDeselect but must be *here* and not *there*
            oldRow = -1
        }
        else {
            print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath => reloadRowsAtIndexPaths")
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
            cell.setSelected(true, animated: false) // must be *after* call to reloadRowsAtIndexPaths
            oldRow = indexPath.row
        }
        print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath: oldRow = '\(oldRow)'")
    }

    //... canEditRowAtIndexPath,  commitEditingStyle
}
```

Below is the custom `UITableViewCell` code (...)

```
import UIKit

class ExistingLocationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() { super.awakeFromNib() }

    // This is where the checkmark happens
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        let nm = self.nameLabel.text
        let ad = self.locationLabel.text
        if (nm?.isEmpty == false) { //avoids many calls to this function which don't represent an actual row
            print("setSelected(\(selected), \(animated)): [name='\(nm)', location='\(ad)']:")
            self.accessoryType = (selected == true) ? .Checkmark : .None
        }
    }

}
```

**LOGGING**

Below is the logging output and images of what I'm seeing (with some additional commentary)

**(1) Initial Display**

  ```
  cellForRowAtIndexPath: (row = 0)(oldRow = -9999)(newRow = -1)[cell.selected = false]
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  cellForRowAtIndexPath: (row = 1)(oldRow = -9999)(newRow = -1)[cell.selected = false]
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-2")', location='Optional("addr-2")']:
  ```
  [image: Initial Display]
  (
  *GOOD: Nothing checked nor highlighted*
  )

**(2) CLICK-1: TOGGLE ON**

  ```
  setSelected(true, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (row = 0)(oldRow = -9999)(newRow = 0)[cell.selected = true]
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath => reloadRowsAtIndexPaths 
  cellForRowAtIndexPath: (row = 0)(oldRow = -9999)(newRow = 0)[cell.selected = false]
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  setSelected(true, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath: oldRow = '0'
  ```
  [image: Initial click]
  (
  *GOOD: row-1 checked and highlighted*
  )

**(3) CLICK-2: TOGGLE OFF**

  ```
  setSelected(true, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  setSelected(true, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (row = 0)(oldRow = 0)(newRow = 0)[cell.selected = true]
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath => didDeselectRowAtIndexPath 
  didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: (row = 0)(oldRow = 0)(newRow = 0)[cell.selected = true]
  didDeselectRowAtIndexPath => reloadRowsAtIndexPaths 
  cellForRowAtIndexPath: (row = 0)(oldRow = 0)(newRow = 0)[cell.selected = false]
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath: oldRow = '-1' 
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  ```
  [image: Second click]
  (
  *GOOD: row-1 un-checked and un-highlighted*
  )

A number of extra calls to `setSelected` appear to happen, not sure why.
**(4) CLICK-3: TOGGLE ON?**

  ```
  setSelected(true, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  setSelected(true, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (row = 0)(oldRow = -1)(newRow = 0)[cell.selected = true]
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath => reloadRowsAtIndexPaths 
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  cellForRowAtIndexPath: (row = 0)(oldRow = -1)(newRow = 0)[cell.selected = false]
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  setSelected(true, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath: oldRow = '0'
  ```
  (
  *BAD: row-1 still un-checked and un-highlighted*
  )
  (
  *the image remains completely the same as above, no matter how many times you click on the same row*
  )
  (
  *if you click on the second row, it goes through the same cycle of appearing to work at first, and then never showing as selected after the 2nd click*
  )

This *should* look the same as the first click on the row, but there are extra calls to `setSelected` and the end-result is wrong.
**(5) CLICK-4: TOGGLE OFF?**

  ```
  setSelected(true, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  setSelected(true, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (row = 0)(oldRow = 0)(newRow = 0)[cell.selected = true]
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath => didDeselectRowAtIndexPath 
  didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: (row = 0)(oldRow = 0)(newRow = 0)[cell.selected = true]
  didDeselectRowAtIndexPath => reloadRowsAtIndexPaths 
  cellForRowAtIndexPath: (row = 0)(oldRow = 0)(newRow = 0)[cell.selected = false]
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath: oldRow = '-1' 
  setSelected(false, false): [name='Optional("name-1")', location='Optional("addr-1")']:
  ```
  (
  *OKAY: row-1 un-checked and un-highlighted, but probably not for the right reason*
  )

**So...** Again, I ask - do you see what I'm doing wrong? Is there something else I should be doing to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot you posted that is hard to get my head around. Nevertheless, one potential problem stands out. I take it that you want the checkmark accessory to indicate the cell is selected, and you have the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("resultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExistingLocationTableViewCell
    let row  = indexPath.row
    let item = locationList[row]

    cell.nameLabel.text     = item.name
    cell.locationLabel.text = item.address
    cell.accessoryType      = .None // initialize accessory icon?

    return cell
}
```

Then in `didSelect` and `didDeselect` you are changing the accessory. This is not how UITableView works. It does not remember state - you have to do this yourself. Within `didSelect`, you should store the indexPath and then reload the table. This will redraw all the visible cells by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` again. Your code there should decide whether or not to display the checkmark using code similar to:

```
cell.accessoryType = (indexPath == mySelectedIndexPath) ? .Checkmark : .None
```

Where `mySelectedIndexPath` is your stored state. This should be defined in your viewController, not in the cell - when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you might get a new cell, or an existing initialized one that has been moved off-screen. Each time you get one, you must assume it contains data for another row, and set everything appropriately.

Comment: As noted (or determined), `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called on initialization *and* if you explicitly call `self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)` or `self.tableView.reloadData()`.  However, neither seemed to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good way to record selected state in the cell.
You can record the selected indexpath in your UITableViewController, and in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, you can find out if it is selected, and what you want to this indexpath.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("resultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExistingLocationTableViewCell

    cell.nameLabel.text     = item.name
    cell.locationLabel.text = item.address

    if indexPath.row == selectedIndexPath { 

        //this cell is selected
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else {
        //this cell is not selected
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("resultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExistingLocationTableViewCell
    if indexPath.row == selectedIndexPath { // ignore the initial blank row
        //do something like deselect
    }
    else {
        //do something like select
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but there's some question as to where/when you update the stored value of the selected row.  The call to  `self.tableView.reloadData()` appears to be somewhat asynchronous, so even if you update the saved value *after* the call to `reloadData`, when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called it seems to pick up the modified value rather than the value that previously existed.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of someone from another list (Ole Begemann), I was able to dramatically clean up my code and get it working [almost] completely.  The one piece that doesn't seem to be working as desired is that the selected row is remaining highlighted rather than the highlighting fading away.

The new code involved all three files:

**LocationObject.swift**
Added a field for tracking the selection state of each set of data:
    // simple class for object that will be used elsewhere, could potentially be replaced with something like UIMapKit, but for now...
    import Foundation

```
class LocationObject {
    var name:      String!
    var address:   String!
    var phone:     String!
    var latitude:  Double!
    var longitude: Double!
    var selected:  Bool!   //<<== Added

    init(name: String, address: String, phone: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double, selected: Bool) { //<<== Added
        self.name      = name
        self.address   = address
        self.phone     = phone
        self.latitude  = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.selected  = false     //<<== Added
    }
}
```

**ExistingLocationTableViewCell.swift**
Unclear if this is even needed, as I essentially removed the customizations I previously made, but keeping it just in case it turns out I need to override or extend something here later.
    import UIKit

```
class ExistingLocationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel:     UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    // Removed override of setSelected() - didn't seem to do anything
}
```

**ExistingLocationsViewController**
This is the primary piece and involved a number of changes and cleanups.
    import UIKit

```
class ExistingLocationsViewController: UITableViewController {
    var oldRow = -1 // Still used for aspect of state information (-1 instead of -9999)
    //newRow removed, wasn't needed
    var locationList: [LocationObject] = [ //<< Added 3rd row of data for more testing
        LocationObject(name: "name-1", address: "addr-1", phone: "phone-1", latitude: 40.0, longitude: -80.1, selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-2", address: "addr-2", phone: "phone-2", latitude: 40.0, longitude: -80.1, selected: false),
        LocationObject(name: "name-3", address: "addr-3", phone: "phone-3", latitude: 40.0, longitude: -80.1, selected: false)
    ]
```

Nothing substantial changed above.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // provides buffer space at the top so that the contents do not run into the top-margin (not needed if first cell is [intnetionally] blank)
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
```

Nothing really changed in the above.
The following are not being shown, for brevity, as there wasn't anything of significance in them:

- `didReceiveMemoryWarning`
- `numberOfSectionsInTableView`
- `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("resultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExistingLocationTableViewCell

        let row  = indexPath.row
        let item = locationList[row]

        cell.nameLabel.text     = item.name
        cell.locationLabel.text = item.address

        return cell
    }
```

Essentially unchanged, removed a debugging statement

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell                   = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ExistingLocationTableViewCell
        let row                    = indexPath.row
        cell.accessoryType         = .None
        locationList[row].selected = false
        oldRow                     = -1
    }
```

The above changed significantly in that it now:

- Uses `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`
- Explicitly sets cell.accessoryType to '`.None`'
- Explicitly sets the `selected` field in LocationObject to '`false`'
- Resets '`oldRow`' to '`-1`' as this function only gets called when de-selecting a *different* previously selected row (i.e.: not a toggle of the *same* row)

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell                   = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ExistingLocationTableViewCell
        let row                    = indexPath.row
        locationList[row].selected = !locationList[row].selected
        cell.accessoryType         = (locationList[row].selected == true) ? .Checkmark : .None
        cell.highlighted           = false
        cell.setHighlighted(false, animated: true)

        if oldRow == row { // TOGGLE
            let oldIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: oldRow, inSection: 0)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(oldIndexPath, animated: true)
            oldRow = -1
        }
        else {
            oldRow = row
        }
    }
}
```

The above changed significantly in that it now:

Uses `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

Sets the `selected` field in LocationObject to it's opposite (`false` => `true` || `true` => `false`)

Uses that value to set the `cell.accessoryType`

If the *same* row was previously selected, deselect it (turn off highlighting)

Set the `oldRow` state information to reference either the currently selected row (selected) or '`-1`' (unselected)

The combination of the above changes solved my issues with trying to get row selection to toggle on secondary taps.  Hopefully this will come in handy for the next person trying to do this...